# Clustering individuals by gene presence/absence

Tags: r, statistics, clustering, pca

I have a binary matrix with individuals as row names, and gene name as column name.
So, if the gene is present in an individual, we have 1, otherwise 0.

I would like to cluster individuals based on the gene presence/absence pattern.

Is it right to perform an MCA? Or a logistic PCA is needed?

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Would you consider hierarchical clustering, i.e. making a tree? However you need to present a test data set and I could give you the tree with an explanation. PCA is okay, but trees have advantages, for reasons I could explain.

Comment: I believe the answers to your question are here:
https://help.ezbiocloud.net/gene-presenceabsence-analysis/
https://www.biostars.org/p/66355/